# LED on the collector without a base limiting resistor

Tags: transistors, npn, load, common-emitter

am a beginner trying to understand transistors.
I am using a npn transistor.

I have a 6V battery.

The base and collector are connected to 6V
Emitter has the load (LED + 100ohm resistor) to the ground.
Current passes and the LED lights up. I understand, it is in saturation mode.
With or without a base resistor.

Case 2:
The base is connected to 6V. 
The collector has the load (LED + 100ohm resistor) connected to 6V as well.
Emitter is connected to the ground.
The LED does not light up when powered.

Case 3: Further to Case 2: I use a 1K resistance with the base and the LED lights up.

Why does not the LED light up in case 2?

This seems similar to [Emitter Follower LED Circuit - LED in Collector, Resistor in Emitter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251111/emitter-follower-led-circuit-led-in-collector-resistor-in-emitter), but I did not get the concept.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to take a step back and understand that an NPN transistor can act like two diodes back to back (sometimes!). In case 2, you're forward-biasing the B-E diode, and it would burn out quickly if the power supply was beefy enough.

Comment: read more how good designs work as switches using Ohm's law and V=I*R drop + diode Vf

Comment: This would be a much better question with actual diagrams of the circuits in your different cases. There is a schematic capture capability when you [edit] the question. Look for the icon above the text entry field that looks like a schematic being drawn (to the right of the one that looks like a picture).

Comment: Which transistor are you using as a model?

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks. I get am forward biasing the BE diode. But so is the case, in case 1 too, right? What sort of biasing is there in the CB diode?

Comment: @Mayken The transistor is a S8050-D331. This one is not listed in the schematic. Please let me know, if this helps.

Comment: In case 1, since the Base and Collector are at the same voltage, no current will flow from C to B. (you must have a voltage across something to have a current through it). All of the current is now moving from B to E and from C to E (because it's acting like a transistor, not just some diodes) but the Emitter has resistance on it, preventing runaway current. So, since all the current comes out at the Emitter, the one resistance at the E terminal is limiting current on both the Base and Collector.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks. Your comment, got me thinking and I read articles on biasing again and in Case 2: without a resistor the FF biasing mode is happening and hence goes into saturation. Putting a resistor on base makes it in FR with the load on collector. http://www.vsagar.org/how-npn-transistor-works-tutorials-of-forward-reverse-biasing/

Answer (score 6):

The LED does not light up because the B-E junction of the transistor is passing enough current to pull the 6V source down to <1V, which is too low to light the LED. It's amazing that the transistor doesn't burn out in this situation, but perhaps it's a rather beefy one, and your 6V supply has a relatively high impedance.

Comment: To which instance are you referring?

Comment: @EMFields: Case 2, the one the OP explicitly asked about: *"Why does not the LED light up in case 2?"*

Comment: @DaveTweed: Is it not the same case when the LED load with 100ohm resistor is on the emitter side? Since there is no 1K resistor connected to the base, in Case 1 too, the B-E diode will pull the source to < 1V? It is not burning because probably I have a switch between my 2, 3V supplies and I switch it on for just a second or two to test my circuit. My motive is in understanding, what is the difference with the load on emitter or collector. The load on emitter does not need a 1K resistor and the load when on collector, needs it.

Comment: No, it is not the same. When you have the LED in series with the emitter, the B-E drop across the transistor is still just 0.7 V or so, but this is not directly across the 6 V power supply -- you end up with about 5.3 V across the LED and its resistor in that configuration.

Comment: @Dave Tweed Thanks. Just to reiterate, you mean: Load (LED + 100ohm resistor) on the collector, the voltage across it is 5.3 V

Comment: @DaveTweed Sorry, it is the other way round. Load on collector: the voltage is <1V since there is no current limiting resistor on the base and with the load on the emitter (LED + 100 ohm resistor): the voltage across the load is 5.3V since base is around 6V and 6-.7 is 5.3V? Another clarification: If am right on understanding what you said, is this the saturation situation with the transistor being used as a switch? If so, how can I reproduce the amplification scenario? Thanks again for taking the effort to reply on basic queries.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for your response. In my response to Daniel, i finally seem to have got it. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does not the LED light up in case 2?

There are two possible reasons assuming you wired it as you state: -

- The 6V power source was "clamped" to about 1 volt because you forced a raw base-emitter region across it. It's a diode after all.
- You blew the transistor base-emitter region up because you didn't use a current limiting resistor.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my extra queries on my comments to Dave Tweed

Comment: When you have an emitter resistor, this is equivalent to having a base resistor that is hFE times bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: with the LED and its series ballast connected between the emitter and ground and the collector and base connected to Vcc, the transistor can **never** go into saturation because the voltage drop across the LED and its ballast resistor will never allow the emitter to see ground.

Case 2. Please post a schematic and post the part number of the transistor in question.

Case 3. Please see case 2

Comment: EMFields: Thanks. I did not get what you say in Case 1. I assumed, it is in saturation and my transistor is acting like a switch here and hence the LED lights up.

Comment: I am using a S8050-D331 : NPN transistor in  the SNAP circuits kit. And a switch between the two 3V batteries. And in Case 1: Saturat

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter errorneously.

Comment: Case1: If it is not in saturation, why does the LED light up? Transistor is acting like a switch here, was my assumption. Do you mean, it is an amplifier here?**Question2:** What is the effect of having the load on collector and emitter and the practical consequences.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel: Thanks. Your comment, got me thinking and I read articles on biasing again and in Case 2: without a resistor the FF biasing mode is happening and hence goes into saturation. Putting a resistor on base makes it in FR with the load on collector. http://www.vsagar.org/how-npn-transistor-works-tutorials-of-forward-reverse-biasing/